# How to configure a Sencha Touch 2 store, to read a multiple level json object

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to connect to an API using a Sencha Touch store and a mode.

The problem represents the API's response json, which is similar to:

```
{
    "The_Api": {
        "initSession":{
            "calledMethod":"The_Api::initSession",
            "status":"1",
            "error":"0",
            "errorCode":"0",
            "errorMessage":"",
            "data":{
                "token":"api_535f6c5d68dc78.56464399"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to retrieve the token value from this response.

How to I configure my store to get to the token value?

```
Ext.define('TestApp.store.SecretKeyStore', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        storeId: 'SecretKeyStore',
        model: "TestApp.model.SecretKeyModel",
        params: {
            lang: 'FR',
            method: 'initSession',
            username: TestApp.utils.GlobalVariables.getUsername(),
            secretKey: TestApp.utils.GlobalVariables.getSecretKey()
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            noCache: true,
            url: '/rest_json.php',
            remoteFilter:true,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What root property should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a js object so this should work:

```
rootProperty:'The_Api.initSession.data'
```